# How to convert date/time from timezone to another timezone in migration process

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm using format_date process plugin to import data from external API to drupal 8 node. 
The date/time in API is "Asia/Jerusalem" time - `2017-06-24 20:52:55` 
The date/time from the API is saved in drupal node as it was a UTC `2017-06-24T20:52:55`
When the node is displayed (I have "Asia/Jerusalem" timezone defined for me) it shows `2017-06-24 23:52:55`

This is the configuration file I used

```
source:   
  fields:
    -
      name: status_updated
      label: 'Status updated'
      selector: status_updated  
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
process:
  field_ext_status_updated:
    plugin: format_date
    from_format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
    to_format: 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'
    #timezone: 'Asia/Jerusalem'
    settings:
     validate_format: false       
    source: status_updated
```

I need either to convert the source date first from "Asia/Jerusalem" to "UTC" and then pass it to format_date or change the configuration file in way that it will save the date as `2017-06-24T17:52:55`so for users with timezone "Asia/Jerusalem" it will show the correct date/time `2017-06-24 20:52:55`

How can I achieve it?
removing the comment for `timezone: 'Asia/Jerusalem'` not helped

Answer (score 1):

Timezone conversion is not yet supported - the issue where it's being developed is https://www.drupal.org/node/2883892.

Comment: Thank you. The issue helped me to write my own process plugin based on format date plugin until it will be supported in core.

Answer (score 0):

Timezone conversion is now supported, with `from_timezone` and `to_timezone` `format_date` plugin parameters.
See updated status of the issue posted by @Mike_Ryan:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2883892

So, above configuration should become:

```
field_ext_status_updated:
  plugin: format_date
  from_format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
  to_format: 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'
  from_timezone: 'Asia/Jerusalem'
  to_timezone: 'UTC'
  settings:
    validate_format: false       
  source: status_updated
```